# How do we perform a perturbative expansion for magnetic monopoles?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, gauge-theory, magnetic-monopoles, duality, non-perturbative

Magnetic monopoles in non-abelian (and even abelian) gauge theory essentially appear as a non-perturbative, composite phenomenon if we perform the standard perturbative expansion in terms of, say, electrons. Moreover, these objects are dual to each other in a certain sense.

So my question is: can we "invert" this? Can we write a perturbative series in terms of the magnetic monopole, and see that a resummation of this series reproduces the existence of the electrons (or whatever the fundamental fields were, originally). Perhaps this may not be tractable, so is there a qualitative way to make this slightly more precise? Or perhaps a rigorous demonstration but in a toy model?

Comment: What you say is essentially the content of S-duality in gauge theory. At weak coupling, one can do perturbation theory with respect to the *electric* degrees of freedom, while at strong coupling perturbation theory can be done w.r.t. *magnetic* degrees of freedom. This type of duality is difficult to prove, but there is a lot of evidence for its existence for certain gauge theories.